# Detecting a null value response and returning true/false

Tags: azure-logic-apps

I have a filtered query to dynamics which could return null in the form of:

```
"value": []
```

I'd want to be able to perform actions on a null response and no action if a value is returned.

My current implementation always returns true for some reason.

I tried using this expression to return true if there's anything returned:

```
"expression": {                       
    "and": [
        {
            "not": {
                 "equals": [
                      "@body('List_records')?['value']",
                      "@null"
                  ]
             }
         }
     ]
}
```

But that didn't work unfortunately (just returns true for everything, including null responses).

Which makes me think that

```
"value":[]
```

Isn't actually null.

I'd appreciate any pointers as I'm fairly new to the code view of logic apps.

Edit:

This works (in case anyone is just as stuck)

```
    "expression": {
                   "and": [
                            {
                             "equals": [
                                 "@length(body('List_records')?['value'])",
                                  0
                               ]
                            }
                        ]
                    },
```

Comment: The value is not null, it's an array without objects. So an array with a count of 0. So you could use the "Length"-function to determine if the array contains any elements or not

Comment: Thanks Steven! That worked.